# CoreBluetooth cannot connect to device nor the fail to connect callback is called for certain devices

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-bluetooth

I am writing a coda that searches for bluetooth devices and then connects to them. I am using the CoreBluetooth Library.

For some devices it works like a charm
For others when it does not connect it calls the failToConnect function which is alright.
But for the main device that I am working on it does not connect nor does it call the didnotconnect delegate function. it simply does not do anything at all

here's some debug statements

```
discovered peripheral named John’s MacBook Pro

discovered peripheral named iPad

discovered peripheral named CB_0000

discovered peripheral named John’s MacBook Pro

attempting to connect the device CB_0000
attempting to connect the device CB_0000
attempting to connect the device CB_0000
attempting to connect the device CB_0000
attempting to connect the device CB_0000
attempting to connect the device iPad
Peer removed pairing information
attempting to connect the device John’s MacBook Pro
successfully connected
```

as you can see it connects to my MacBook pro
it fails to connect to the iPad but at least it calls to failtoconnect function and it sayspeer removed pairing information

however, CB_0000 does not do anything at all

here's the simplified version of the code

```
class BLEManager : NSObject, ObservableObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    var central_manager : CBCentralManager!
    @Published var peripherals : [CBPeripheral] = []
    override init() {
        super.init()
        central_manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        }
    }
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        guard let name = peripheral.name else {return}
        print("discovered peripheral named \(name)\n")
        peripheral.delegate = self
        peripherals.append(peripheral)
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("successfully connected")
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        print("updated state")
    }
}
```

```
struct DeviceVC: View {
    @StateObject var blemanager = BLEManager()
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(blemanager.peripherals, id: \.self) {device in
                Text(device.name!)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        blemanager.central_manager.connect(device, options: nil)
                        print("attempting to connect the device \(device.name!)")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought maybe it's becasue of SwiftUI being buggy, so I built the application using UIKit but result was the same.

Comment: Can you connect to that peripheral using the LightBlue app or the Nordic app from the App Store?

Comment: Nope, when I try CB_000 it is stuck in the loading screen until timeout. Edit: I was using LightBlue app

Comment: Then there is a problem with the peripheral.

Comment: is there anything I can do? should I contact the company?

Comment: Do you believe CB_0000 should be connectable? Not every bluetooth device is. It should advertise that it isn't connectable in that case (CBAdvertisementDataIsConnectable will be false), but I've see people set that incorrectly, particularly in prototypes if they're copying sample code. I've also seen this with buggy firmware, especially if they don't support Bluetooth 5 correctly and you're using a newer phone. (I agree with Paul that this is likely the device. Whether you contact the company depends on your relationship with the company.)